# how to store data at row[0] in csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, plotly-dash

I am working on live data using python. I am storing the data in csv file and showing that data to user using dash data table. Because the daily data may be very long so it it difficult for user to scroll whole data every time to see the latest live data. So what I want to do is I want to store the newest data in csv at the very first row i.e on row[0]. So the current data will be displayed on top of the data table.

```
df = pd.read_csv("myfile.csv")
df = df.loc[::-1]
```

But as I said I am working on live data so it is reversing and re-reversing the csv every time when the data is coming.

Please help me to get the solution of my query
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I am working on live data so it is reversing and re-reversing the csv every time when the data is coming." I don't understand. If you are working on live data, then why does the file get read more than once? Why not just keep using the same `df` value?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand correctly, but:

If you want only to display first row:

```
df.query('index == 0')
```

If you want to add data at the first row:

```
df.loc[-1] = ['data1', 'data2', 'data3']
df.index = df.index + 1
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
```